# WordPress - Breadcrumbs Register Button Modification

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook

I am currently modifying a theme called Auction by Premium Press. In this theme you can easily create child themes, which is what I am doing. I need to edit the header file so that I can edit a register button to redirect to a different page instead of wp-login. I understand I will need to use hooks and filters in order to change these elements however I don't fully understand what I should do.

BTW it is using breadcrumbs.

Theme link: http://www.premiumpress.com/auctiontheme/

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin to redirect after login:

Peter's Login Redirect
https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Maybe it is what you are looking for.

**Added after user feedback:**

You might want to consider adding a link to the menu. I can think of two ways of complishing this:

1) Go to Admin Panel > Appearance > Menu and add a **link** to the main menu pointing to the url of your choice

2) Copy header.php file to your theme-child and add a link where you want it to be. For example:

`<a href="http://example.com" id="my-nav-link">Go to Example</a>`

Then you can use the `#my-nav-link` to style it in CSS as you would would like. Your theme might have a standard button class already. So you might want to do that. For example `class="button button-primary button-small"`. So you final button code might look like:

`<a href="http://example.com" id="my-nav-link" class="button button-primary button-small">Go to Example</a>`

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hey thanks for this. However I don't want a login direct I need a button to redirect to a different page on my menu. However, it is part of the header that I need to access

Comment: I see. Then you want a link on your header. There are two ways I can think of accomplishing this.

Comment: Ok. What would them ways be? I have been looking around and think that I could maybe construct the code like such: if particular url is entered then redirect to this url. 

Would this work?